# Why entity properties are null in class

Tags: php, symfony

When I create an entity with the MakerBundle and I set a property NOT NULLABLE, why in my class do I still have:

- The nullable type (e.g. `?string`)
- The `= null` after property name (e.g. `$name = null`)
- The nullable type in the getter return value (e.g. `?string`)

Example:

1. Execute `php bin/console make:entity Car`
2. Add property `name`
3. Set `Can this field be null in the database (nullable) (yes/no)`  to no
4. Add property `description`
5. Set `Can this field be null in the database (nullable) (yes/no)`  to yes

And in my class I have that:

```
{
    ...
    private ?string $name = null;

    private ?string $description = null;

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
    ...
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    ...
    private string $name;

    private ?string $description = null;

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `$o = new Car(); $name = $o->getName();` `getName` returns what? `NULL`

Comment: Not nullable hints to the field not able to be NULL in the DB not in the PHP code..

Comment: The maintainer of the make:entity command has very definite ideas on what the default behavior should be.  Not everyone agrees with all of their decisions.  I for one want an error to be tossed if a non-nullable property is set to null.  The save/remove methods in the repository are also a bit questionable in my opinion.  You can override the templates that the make:entity uses if you want.  Otherwise you just need to resign yourself to editing.

Comment: It is an intentional design of the MakerBundle author.

Comment: Making PHP properties not nullable when it isn't absolutely necessary kinda goes against the point of using PHP in the first place IMO.

Comment: @hugoschweitzer Why is that?  PHP has been trending to being more and more typesafe.  If a property should never be null then why would you not use the language to enforce it?

Comment: @Cerad "If a property should never be null (...)" yes that's what I meant with "when it isn't absolutely necessary". You should still enforce good practices when they make sense. You should also take advantage of PHP and Symfony's features rather than blindly force them to behave like other languages.